# HTML5 video is the wrong size on iPad

Tags: ipad, html5-video

I build an interactive game consisting of HTML5 videos with sometimes, clickable png layer over it to add interactivity.

It's pretty simple and it works great on Chrome/Firefox, but I'm trying to make it work for iPad and I have a problem: Whatever the size I put in my CSS or in the `<video>` tag, the video is showing smaller on iPad.

I'm using VideoJS to manage events on HTML5 videos.

You can test at http://megalobio.com. It's in french, but easy to understand, just Facebook login to open the game (no data is saved, only for game building purpose).

I desperately need some help, this has kept me busy for days...

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @mat Yes, the iPad was selecting a format thats was badly converted, the .ogv.

Comment: Okay.. My formats are good and work everywhere. But the MP4 is shown correctly on an iPad with VideoJS and good without VideoJS

Comment: If you look at the code you'll see the video tag `width` and `height` attributes get replaced with nothing when the player is initialized. My fix was just to set values for the element using css like so. `.vjs-tech {width: 900px; height: 506px;}` Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you can avoid this by settings a correct [viewport meta tag](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/)

Try adding this line in your

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

You might also want to change the value according to [device orientation](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-orientation/)

another recommended read [here](http://x7.fi/2010/02/12/how-to-fit-your-website-for-the-apple-ipad/)

Comment: Not working, The window is perfect fit when I set the viewport, but the video is inside a div block, and is still too small to fit the block... Any other idea?